# Wireless works under Gnome but not under KDE on the same Laptop

Tags: gnome, wireless, kde, broadcom

After browsing random old answered questions on this site I found the method to install KDE Plasma Desktop 'on-top-of" the standard Ubuntu Gnome Desktop. (I don't think I've worded that right :-))

My Laptop worked 100% OOTB with Ubuntu 11.04 and I have not had many problems with the hardware apart from issues with the battery montior so I am 100% sure this is a software issue.

As soon as I log into Gnome my wireless connection activates, connects and sits in the background working fine however in KDE is finds the SSID under the scan option in the network options but then will not connect to it or find it in the network option on the top of the screen.

I am not at all apt with the KDE system so I can not give you a log output or anything like that so as vague as this question may be I would love some help with this issue.

Gnome is using the Broadcom STA driver

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager in KDE? You might need to install the NetworkManager KDE applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have the plasma-widget-networkmanagement installed, if so, try adding it to the plasma desktop and it should work.

If it don't, then after starting KDE open a terminal and run nm-applet, that's the Network Manager used on Gnome, so if it worked in gnome it should work in KDE. =D